# What's "\." in postgresql dump file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dump

I have a Postgresql dump file which i'm trying to restore. I get this error regarding an invalid data i guess.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "."

and when i checked the file, there are data like this:

```
469215  2009-10-10 18:16:47.041377  0   1
471217  2009-10-10 18:25:12.536352  0   1
473224  2009-10-17 09:46:43.041604  0   1
473228  2009-10-22 10:58:40.194244  0   1
.
```

so i was wondering what is this "." do?
i check some other working dumps and they ended their data line with "." which i guess it's the correct syntax!

Please tell me what's the correct syntax and what does it do?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that it marks the end of a COPY statement

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html)

```
End of data can be represented by a single line containing just backslash-period (\.).
 An end-of-data marker is not necessary when reading from a file, since the end of file 
serves perfectly well; it is needed only when copying data to or from client
applications using pre-3.0 client protocol.
```

Comment: is there any way to get around it? kinda like set it to ignore it? cause the dump file is almost 12million lines and it's a pain to search all copy statements and replace the end of them to "\." !

Comment: Don't know of one off the top of my head.  However, it should be pretty easy to use some utility like "sed" to change it painlessly...

Comment: You might want to try to figure out how it happened in the first place before you just go edit the file - pg_dump will always generate the proper terminator... (This is one more reason to always use the "custom" dump format, of course)

Comment: well actually the data is not a actual pg_dump format, it's raw data recovered from the disk. i found a way! i used a python piece of code to convert those "." in a new line to "\." :)